# Internet music player can't load songs when device locked (Doze mode?)

Tags: android, networking, exoplayer, android-doze

I'm building a music player which plays songs from the internet. What I notice is that, often, when a song ends and another one has to be loaded, the app does not play the following song.

I wait, wait, wait when finally I decide to unlock my phone to understand what's happening. Surprisingly immediately after the device has been unlocked the following song starts.

The first time I thought it was just a coincidence, but after many times the same thing happened now I think it is systematic. The only cause I can imagine is the Doze mode (I'm using a device with Android 7.1), I've already configured the app to use a `WakeLock` (a `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`) but it does not seem to be much help.

**Edit**
I'm sure the problem is the Doze mode. If the device is plugged or if the screen is on (or both) the problem vanishes. If I add my app to the unoptimized apps' list also it works well.