# Ignore Battery Optimization for radio application

Tags: android

When my online radio application goes in doze mode there is no network access because of which the radio stops working.Even the wake locks don't work in doze mode.
I've added the intent as per qouted in documentation.

> An app holding the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission can
>   trigger a system dialog to let the user add the app to the whitelist
>   directly, without going to settings. The app fires a
>   ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS Intent to trigger the
>   dialog.

Here is the intent.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
```

also i have added permission in manifest because the intent is not working without it.
Is it safe to use this permission in a radio application?

Comment: you have to implement a foreground service to prevent your app from being killed

Comment: i used background service for playing music in background. But this doze mode behavior is in Android 6.0 and above only. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: you need not a `background` service, but `foreground`?

Comment: ok so foreground services are not affected by doze mode? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: it does not let device to enter doze mode while the foreground service is running

Comment: yes but still there is alot of discussion on this as you see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869201/how-does-doze-mode-affect-background-foreground-services-with-without-partial-f

Comment: and you must read this too . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834195/mediaplayer-doze-mode-wake-lock-foreground-service
whitelsting is needed somehow . So can you answer what my real question is? It will be helpful. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: I don't think I must read anything, I'm OK with what I know. It works for me

Comment: well what i think , you also have to add broad cast receiver for check, in case your service is destroyed then you can again start the service

Comment: you can read more about different types of permissions in android system. safe and dangerous. if this permission comes under safe permission you dont need to add.